# Do you have to say "mi casa" or can you just say "casa"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres

So I'm beginning Spanish, and I was wondering- in the sentence "yo voy a mi casa", can you just say "voy a casa"? I know you can omit the pronoun without any worry, but do you have to say "mi casa"?

Comment: I'd say "la casa" is more common than "casa". Omitting the determiner would sound quite weird.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can omit it.  The meanings are slightly different.

> Voy a mi casa

means *I'm going to my house.*

> Voy a casa

means *I'm going home.*

As I learned from a comment, the second version doesn't work in all countries, for example, it would apparently be quite unusual in Colombia where people usually include the "mi" and almost always use the preposition "para": **"Voy para mi casa"**.

Comment: I agree and BTW there are regional differences.  In Colombia you will almost never hear someone saying "voy a casa" without "mi" while in Spain I think the opposite is true (Spaniards, please confirm or reject my statement).

Comment: @DGaleano Indeed, in Spain we'd say "voy a casa" unless we wanted to stress the "mi" for some reason.

Comment: @aparente001 "Ya me voy a la casa" would not be common in Colombia. We would say "Ya me voy a mi casa" and more commonly you will hear "Ya me voy para mi casa". We almost never omit **mi** and almost always use "para" or its unofficial contraction " pa' " **(Me voy pa' mi casa)**

Answer (score 1):

You can omit the pronoun and keep the meaning, but you cannot omit the preposition

> Yo voy **a** mi casa andando los viernes
>
> Voy **a** casa en coche los lunes
>
> Estoy cansado. Me voy **a** (mi) casa

Comment: I agree, and also you can use another preposition like "para" as we always do in Colombia. **Estoy cansado. Me voy para mi casa**

Comment: Seems a bit tangential to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers, note that you can omit "mi" from "mi casa" because the meaning can be inferred. In other cases omitting it would be inappropriate or incorrect:

- Where you need to stress "mi":

> -- ¿Vamos a mi casa o a tu casa?
>
> -- A *mi* casa.

- With other nouns: "Voy en auto" and "voy en mi auto" mean (slightly) different things ("I go by car" [maybe a friend's, not by train] and "I go in my car").